# Action of the Galois group on a variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

Let $X$ be an affine variety over a field $k$ and let $L/k$ be a finite Galois extension of Galois group $G$.

1. Is it correct that the action of $\sigma \in G$ on $X_L := X \times_{Spec k} Spec L$ is defined as being 
   $$id_X \times Spec(\sigma) : X_L \to X_L$$ ?
2. For any $L$-algebra $A$, what is the action of $\sigma \in G$ on the $A$-points $X_L(A) := Hom_L(Spec(A), X_L)$ ?
   The moprhism $id_X \times Spec(\sigma) : X_L \to X_L$ **do not** induce maps $X_L(A) \to X_L(A)$, because $id_X \times Spec(\sigma)$ is a $K$-morphism and not a $L$-morphism.
   So how can I define the Galois action on $X_L(A)$, or at least on $X_L(L)$ ?
   $$ $$
   There is a possibility for the action on an $L$-point $x \in X(L) = X_L(L)$, namely
   $$\sigma \cdot x := (id_X \times Spec(\sigma^{-1})) \circ x \circ Spec(\sigma)$$
   (as an $L$-morphism from $Spec(L)$ to $X_L$).
   $$ $$
   But I am confused by the fact that it is $id_X \times Spec(\sigma^{-1})$ that appears (instead of $id_X \times Spec(\sigma)$), and by the fact that I can't generalize this to an action of $\sigma$ on $X_L(A)$ for *any* $L$-algebra $A$. Is my definition of $\sigma \cdot x$ correct, at least?

Comment: 1. Usually people use $\text{Spec}(\sigma^{-1})$ because it's more geometric (i.e. since the Spec functor is defined by taking preimages, whatever you want to get you should start with and whatever you want to start with you should get).

2. the map $X_L(A)\rightarrow X_L(A)$ is the one that's induced by the $K$-morphism.

Comment: @Eoin : thank you very much for your comment! For 1.), I was thinking also that $Spec(\sigma^{-1})$ is better because we want a left action (and Spec is a contravariant functor...). For 2.), I was mistaken : while the map $x \mapsto \sigma \cdot x$ is well-defined $X_L(L) \to X_L(L)$, the $K$-morphism $id \times Spec(\sigma)$ (or $id \times Spec(\sigma^{-1})$) _don't_ induce maps $X_L(A) \to X_L(A)$, since it is a $K$-morphism and not a $L$-morphism! We only have $X_L(A) \to Hom_K(Spec(A), X_L)$...